# Append only non empty cells to another sheet google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, filtering, google-sheets-api

I want to copy only non-empty cells in column C & E & append all of them in "Update" Sheet 1st column. Below is what i tried for copy non-empty cells but it doesnt append 
here is [Dummy Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1flbMoOaO2PQ2jYsQq0dL3UBlQWsol7wZpxKO-uUtQn0/edit#gid=574186593) for reference

```
  function emaillFilter(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Email");
  var updateSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Update");
  var range = ws.getRange(1,5,ws.getLastRow());

   var emptycells = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().setHiddenValues(['']).build(); 
   var filter = range.getFilter() || range.createFilter();
       filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(5, emptycells);
  var data = ws.getRange(2,5,ws.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var array = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    if(!ws.isRowHiddenByFilter(i+1)){  
       array.push(data[i]);
    }
  }
  updateSheet.getRange(updateSheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, array.length).setValues(array);
}
```

input sheet Column C & E

[image: input]

desired output - paste column C & append E without blanks in column A of another sheet

[image: output]

Comment: Please don't ask several questions at a time. Also, provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or an example of the Sheet and the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
function emaillFilter(){
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName("Email");
  const ush=ss.getSheetByName("Update");
  const data=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow(),5).getValues();
  var array=[];
  data.forEach(function(r,i){
    if(r[2] && r[4]) {
      array.push(r);
    }
  });
  ush.getRange(ush.getLastRow()+1, 1, array.length,array[0].length).setValues(array);
}
```

Okay I think you want this based upon your comment:

> desired output - paste column C & append E without blanks in column A of another sheet

But I must admit that I don't see that reflected in your example second image so we may need another iteration.

```
function emaillFilter(){
      const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      const sh=ss.getSheetByName("Email");
      const ush=ss.getSheetByName("Update");
      const data=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow(),5).getValues();
      var array=[];
      data.forEach(function(r,i){
        //is columnC and columnE both truth
        if(r[2] && r[4]) {
          array.push([r[2] + ',' + r[4]]);
          //is columnC truthy and columnE falsy
        }else if(r[2] && !r[4]) {
          array.push([r[2]]);
        }
      });
      ush.getRange(ush.getLastRow()+1, 1, array.length,array[0].length).setValues(array);
    }
```

Okay I think this is it:

```
function emaillFilter(){
      const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      const sh=ss.getSheetByName("Email");
      const ush=ss.getSheetByName("Update");
      const data=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow(),5).getValues();
      var array1=[];
      var array2=[];
      data.forEach(function(r,i){
        if(r[2]) {
          array1.push([r[2]]);
        }
        if(r[4]) {
          array2.push([r[4]]);
        }
      });
      var array=array1.concat(array2);
      ush.getRange(ush.getLastRow()+1, 1, array.length,array[0].length).setValues(array);
    }
```

Thanks for the images.  They really helped.

[truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)

[falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)

Comment: Thanks Cooper , it works partially its not copying all data in column C instead its taking only rows which has data in column E,   i want to copy all non-empty rows in _column C  & E_ and append both column in _update sheet 1st column only_ .

Comment: I have added two screenshot in question of inputsheet and desired output sheet hope that helps

Comment: i edited images, what i want is column C & E of input to be pasted in Column A of output without empty cells

Comment: Oh I see.  Do they have to be at the bottom?